# What does "stealth candidate" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

One of the meanings of the word "*stealth*" from [thefreedictionary.com](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/stealth):
stealth - (as an adjective) not disclosing one's true ideology, affiliations, or positions:
*a stealth candidate*

The collocation "*stealth candidate*" seemed interesting to me but proceeding from the explanation above, I didn't quite understand what it means. Could you explain it please?

Comment: @Sam, I think if your own level of English is not good, you should not try to teach others and write them "_I think you got it_".

Comment: I think you did not understand my answer??

Answer (score 2):

A stealth candidate would be a candidate  who did not reveal his true ideology, affiliations, or position.

He is, in effect, telling a lie of omission.

It could apply to a political office, an election to the board of a corporation, or even a job applicant.

Suppose a candiate, Mr. Fox, wants to get elected. And suppose there is some person who is highly controversial. Call him Mr. Orange. Associating with that person is perceived to be a detriment to the chances of getting elected. However, Mr. Orange has command of resources that can be very helpful getting elected. Could be connections, back room influence, etc.

So it might be valuable to Mr. Fox to *be* associated with Mr. Orange. But at the same time not let it be *known* that he was associated. So Mr. Orange might do secret favors for Mr. Fox. And Mr. Fox might avoid the controversy associated with Mr. Orange.

The same could apply to the ideology held by Mr. Fox. Perhaps he plans, if he gets into office, to enact certain policies. And he perceives that these policies would not be popular during the election. So he simply does not mention them during the campaign. He mentions only his policies he believes will be popular.

By concealing his associations and ideology, Mr. Fox is a stealth candidate.